# Trying to use regex in vim to change email headers

Tags: vim

A user accidentally deleted all emails    from inbox, saved folders, trash etc. I'm trying to make bulk change to all the headers in the files to "read" instead of a "deleted"

The header is

```
X-Mozilla-Status: ****
```

where **** is any combination of numbers/letters, and I'm trying to change them all to 0001

So far my command is this:

```
:%s/^X-Mozilla-Status: \([0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]\)/X-Mozilla-Status: \1/
```

However its coming out with 0013, 0011, 0301 etc instead of 0001

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just write `0001` instead of `\1`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
%s/X-Mozilla-Status:.*/X-Mozilla-Status: 0001
```